# This specific C code snippet doesn't seem to build and run in the Code:Blocks IDE

Tags: c, ide

Yes, I had googled the specific problem, which was a /n snippet of the code, but it gives me error messages.

Here's the code

```
{
    printf("Godsmack" \n);
    printf("I don't watch movies" \n);
    printf("My cat likes Adventure Time" \n);
    printf("11 meters per second" \n);
}
```

The error messages read: Line 10 (first line):

```
... error: stray ‘\’ in program
     printf("Godsmack" \n);
                       ^
```

And line 10:

```
... expected ")" before ‘n’
```

Line 11 (same messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\n` needs to be part of your string:

```
{
    printf("Godsmack \n");
    printf("I don't watch movies \n");
    printf("My cat likes Adventure Time \n");
    printf("11 meters per second \n");
}
```